# Styling list items that do not only contain other lists

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I've made a table of contents generator based on the `<h1>...<h6>` tags within an HTML document. I'm trying to add custom bullet point icons before the resulting sets of lists-within-lists. I managed to get this to work for simple `<h1>...<h2>...<h3>` progressions by using the `li:before` CSS selector, but this falls apart for progressions that skip levels, e.g. `<h1>...<h3>`:

[image: list with unwanted bullet point on empty line]

Without the `li:before` property, the intermediate list doesn't produce a new line:

[image: list without bullet points]

This is what I'd like:

[image: list with bullet points only on entries with text]

Is there a way to do this, perhaps using some way to select only `<li>` elements whose first child is `<a>`? My experience with modern CSS trickery is limited.

Here is a minimal example:

```css
.contents ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.contents ul li:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f105';
}
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  <ul> <!-- h1 level -->
    <li>
      <a href="#top-level">Top level</a>
      <ul> <!-- h2 level -->
        <li>
          <ul> <!-- h3 level -->
            <li>
              <a href="#third-level">Third level</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For reference, I'm using FontAwesome's [`angle-right`](https://fontawesome.com/icons/angle-right?style=solid) icon (interestingly, the example snippet seems to load this font).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.contents ul li:before` to `.contents ul li:first-child a:before` like this

```css
    
    .contents ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .contents ul li:first-child a:before  {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        content: '\f105';
    }
```

```html
    
    <div class="contents">
      <ul> <!-- h1 level -->
        <li>
          <a href="#top-level">Top level</a>
          <ul> <!-- h2 level -->
            <li>
              <ul> <!-- h3 level -->
                <li>
                  <a href="#third-level">Third level</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify want you wanted with example so I can modify my post??

Comment: That works! So it was really simple in the end. I should have included extra list items to show exactly what I wanted, but indeed I wanted a right-arrow next to each entry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @FridayAmeh's answer to identify **only** the *first* `li` with an anchor and apply the styling to that.

You will require

```
.contents ul li:first-child > a:before
```

Such as...

```css
.contents ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.contents ul li:first-child>a:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f105";
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -.4em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="contents">
  <ul>
    <!-- h1 level -->
    <li>
      <a href="#top-level">Top level</a>
      <ul>
        <!-- h2 level -->
        <li>
          <ul>
            <!-- h3 level -->
            <li>
              <a href="#third-level">Third level</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#third-level">Third level</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I wanted to have right-arrows next to each item, which wasn't clear, sorry. It seems that @Friday Ameh's answer works.